# How to perform component labelling in a .bmp(binary image) containing digits 9 4 3 6?

Tags: c++, c++11, image-processing, c++14

I have [a binary BMP image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9way.png) of size 284x1280. The image contains the digits 9 4 3 6. I want to perform component labelling on the image and mark the labels whenever the digits occur. Initially, it is a binary image with only 0 and 1 in the 2D array (0 marked as background and 1 marked as the digits)

I tried to write a component labelling function (checking 8 neighbours) and incrementing a counter whenever I find a component labelled 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int func(int w, int h, int a[][1280], int i, int j, int c)
{
 if(i==h||j==w)
  {
   return 0;
  }
 if(a[i][j+1]==1)
  {
a[i][j+1]=c; return func(w,h,a,i,j+1,c);
  }
 if(a[i+1][j]==1)
  {
a[i+1][j]=c; return func(w,h,a,i+1,j,c);
  }
 if(a[i+1][j+1]==1)
  {
a[i+1][j+1]=c; return func(w,h,a,i+1,j+1,c);
  }
 else
  {
    return 0;
  }
  }

 unsigned char* read_bmp(char *fname, int* _w, int* _h)
   {
    unsigned char head[54];
    FILE *f=fopen(fname,"rb");
    //BMP header is 54 bytes
    fread(head,1,54,f);
    int w=head[18]+(((int)head[19]) << 8)+(((int)head[20]) << 16)+ 
    (((int)head[21]) << 24);
    int h=head[22]+(((int)head[23]) << 8)+(((int)head[24]) << 16)+ 
    (((int)head[25]) << 24);
    //lines are aligned on 4-byte boundary
    int lineSize = (w / 8 + (w / 8) % 4);
    int fileSize=lineSize * h;
    unsigned char *img, *data;
    img =(unsigned char*)malloc(w * h), data =(unsigned 
    char*)malloc(fileSize);
    //skip the header
    fseek(f,54,SEEK_SET);
    //skip palette - two rgb quads, 8 bytes
    fseek(f,8,SEEK_CUR);
    //read data
    fread(data,1,fileSize,f);
    //decode bits
    int i, j, k, rev_j;
    for(j=0, rev_j=h-1;j<h;j++,rev_j--)
    {
      for(i=0;i<w/8;i++)
      {
        int fpos= j * lineSize + i, pos = rev_j * w + i * 8;
         for(k=0;k<8;k++)
          {
           img[pos+(7-k)]=(data[fpos] >> k) & 1;
          }
       }
    }
     free(data);
     *_w = w; *_h = h;
     return img;
   }


   int main()
   {
    int w, h, i, j, c1=0, c2=0, c3=0, c4=0, c5=0, c6=0;
    unsigned char* img=read_bmp("binary.bmp",&w,&h);
    int array[h][1280];
    char ch;
    for(j=0;j<h;j++)
     {
       for(i=0;i<1280;i++)
       {
        array[j][i]=(int(img[j * w + i])==0);
       }
     }
      register int c=2;
      for(i=0;i<h;i++)
      {
        for(j=0;j<1280;j++)
        {
          if(array[i][j]==1)
          {
            array[i][j]=c;
            func(w,h,array,i,j,c);
          }
       }
     }
      for(i=0;i<h;i++)
      {
       for(j=0;j<w;j++)
       {
         printf("%d",array[i][j]);
       }
      printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

I am getting an array of just 0 and 2, whereas it should contain 0,2,3,4,5 labels for other digits. How to fix it?

Comment: `int func()` - that's not the most helpful name. In general. I'd say the code quality is rather low. `register` ?! that makes me think you're new to programming. What you need most here is test cases. Not big arrays, but simple 8*8 arrays with a few pixels set. You should be able to manually verify the whole logic.

Comment: I tried the similar, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It’s not cool to completely change your question after you’ve gotten an answer. It makes the answer meaningless. Instead, accept the answer if it was useful in solving your problem, and then ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I don't know why, it has been downvoted and I am not able to ask further question until 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

1. You never increment `c`, hence you get stuck at label 2.
2. Once you fix that, you’ll notice single objects being broken up into many labels. This is because you check only 3 neighbors in your recursive function. You need to check all 8 (or 4 for 4-connected neighborhood). Yes, your recursive function must be able also to travel to the left and up to follow complex shapes.
3. This recursive function is very inefficient and with an object large enough it could cause a stack overflow. You could instead write a loop that propagates all along the line within the object. The best algorithms for object labeling use the union-find algorithm, I encourage you to look that up.